# How can i launch multiple browser instances with different sessions using puppeteer

Tags: session-cookies, puppeteer, multiple-instances

Right now I'm using a single session cookie with a browser instance to authenticate, I want to launch multiple instances with different sessions so that I can authenticate to different accounts sequentially or parallelly using recursion.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async ()=>{

    const browser= await puppeteer.launch({
            "headless": false,
            "slowMo":50

    });


    const page= await browser.newPage(); 

    var cookie = [

        {
            "domain": ".www.example.com",
            "expirationDate": 55102.289054,
            "hostOnly": false,
            "httpOnly": true,
            "name": "dokl",
            "path": "/",
            "sameSite": "no_restriction",
            "secure": true,
            "session": false,
            "storeId": "0",
            "value": "PQYv5oCnyhx66qOzqtVxIoPYuzSq6p2wpd5365YkPCgHUqLY0reaiB",
            "id": 17
        }

        ]
    await page.setCookie(...cookie)
    await page.goto("https://www.example.com/");
    console.log(await page.content())
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the browser cache & delete cookies after each iteration with the following code:

```js
const cdpClient = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await cdpClient.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
await cdpClient.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');
```

Comment: thanks, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845736/how-set-cookie-from-array-of-json-file-objects-using-loop

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution if it works out for you!